# Show the numbers and dots as a result only

Tags: vb.net

My program has

> FlatTextBox1
>   
>   FlatButton1
>   
>   FlatAlertBox1

So, I've made it, when you type something in the textbox and click the button, it requests from an url and returns the result to the alertbox. My question is, how do I make it so it only returns the first numbers and dots? For example, if it returns:

```
Success: 255.255.255.255 <br><br><br> Old Success: 127.0.0.1
```

I want it to only show

```
255.255.255.255
```

Comment: Why don't you try with regex or substring, then update the question

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this is string manipulation via substring:

```
    Dim sResult As String = "Success: 255.255.255.255 <br><br><br> Old Success: 127.0.0.1"  ' This is hardcoded for the example
    Dim nIndex1 As Int32 = sResult.IndexOf(" ") ' Find the first blank space character (after Success:)
    Dim nIndex2 As Int32 = sResult.IndexOf("<br>")  ' Find the first br tag (after the space which is after the ip address we want to capture)

    sResult = sResult.Substring(nIndex1, nIndex2 - nIndex1).Trim    ' Use substring to get the ip address and trim off the excess spaces
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, my string is named IP, so do I change sResult to IP?

Comment: Yes, you can omit the first line in my answer since you are getting the ip string via another method and then the last line would change to: `IP = IP.Substring(nIndex1, nIndex2 - nIndex1).Trim`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your string by using `string.remove`

```
Dim sResult As String = "Success: 255.255.255.255 <br><br><br> Old Success: 127.0.0.1"  
Dim break = sResult.IndexOf("<br>") 'find the first time it says "<br>"
Dim sresult = sResult.Remove(break) 'remove from the string
```